# How to Titanium Command Line Interface to build iPhone app ready for App Store

Tags: ios, titanium

Lately, I want to write a simple script to automatically build titanium project. Here is my script:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2 
3 platform='ios'
4 developer_name='XXXXX XXXX'
5 device_family='iphone'
6 distribution_name='/Users/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/YY_mobile_app.mobileprovision'
7 ios_version='6.1'
8 pp_uuid='XXXX155D-XXXX-XXXX-CCBR-XXCXX5226XXX'
9 target='dist-appstore'
10 
11 titanium build --platform ${platform}  -F ${device_family} -I ${ios_version}  -T ${target}  -R ${distribution_name} -P ${pp_uuid} -V ${developer_name}
```

But I keep getting this error

```
 [ERROR] No distribution or adhoc provisioning profiles found
```

Even though the provision profile(distribution_name,pp_uuid) I provided was definitely valid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 828 views as of Aug 3rd 2017 and no answers?